# Manipulating strings in python - concentrating on part of a user's input

Tags: python

```
    resp = raw_input("What is your favorite fruit?\n")
if "I like" in resp:
    print "%s" - "I like" + " is a delicious fruit." % resp
else:
    print  "Bubbles and beans."
```

OK I  know this code doesn't work, and I know why.  You can't subtract strings from each other like numbers.

But is there a way to break apart a string and only use part of the response?
And by "is there a way" I really mean "how," because anything is possible in programming. :D

I'm trying to write my first chatterbot from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to simply replace the part that you want to remove with an empty string:

```
resp = raw_input("What is your favorite fruit?\n")
if "I like" in resp:
    print "%s is a delicious fruit." % (resp.replace("I like ", ""))
else:
    print  "Bubbles and beans."
```

If you want to look into more advanced pattern matching to grab out more specific parts of strings via flexible patterns, you might want to look into [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Also string.split() for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
# python
  "I like turtles".replace("I like ","")
'turtles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with regular expressions:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: pat = r'(I like )*(\w+)( is a delicious fruit)*'

In [3]: print re.match(pat, 'I like apples').groups()[1]
apples

In [4]: print re.match(pat, 'apple is a delicious fruit').groups()[1]
apple
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you just strip "I like"?

```
resp.strip("I like")
```

be careful of case sensitivity though.

Comment: strip() doesn't do what you think it does.  "I like apple".strip("I like") becomes "app".